# White border at top of application cannot be removed

Tags: xamarin

I noticed that I have a white strip at the top of all my application pages today. I am using navigation view and I imported a third party NuGet package called Magic Gradients. I have tried to do some debugging today before posting and even after deleting each and every "part" I'm still getting this white strip on the top of all my application pages.

Heres my code

For LoginPage.xaml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             xmlns:local1 ="clr-namespace:PluralBuddy"
             xmlns:magicGradients="clr-namespace:MagicGradients;assembly=MagicGradients"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="PluralBuddy.Views.LoginPage">

    <ContentPage.Content >

        <Grid BackgroundColor="Transparent">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="60" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                <RowDefinition Height="35" />
                <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                <RowDefinition Height=".5*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                <RowDefinition Height="30" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="60" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Source="{local1:ImageResource PluralBuddy.Images.PluralBuddyLogo2.png}" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.RowSpan="4"></Image>
            <Entry Placeholder="Username" x:Name="User_Name"  PlaceholderColor="#DADDFB"   Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="6"/>
            <Entry Placeholder ="Password" x:Name="Pass_Word" PlaceholderColor="#DADDFB" IsPassword="True" Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="6"/>
            <Button Text="Login" Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" BackgroundColor="#DAFBF8" Clicked="LoginCommand"/>
            <RelativeLayout Grid.Column="3" Grid.Row="8" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                <Label Grid.Row="8" Grid.Column="2" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Text="Dont have an account?" VerticalOptions="Center" 
                       RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Constant=1}"
                       RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Constant=1}"></Label>
            <Frame CornerRadius="5"
                   OutlineColor="Transparent"
                   Padding="0"
                   BorderColor="Transparent"
                   RelativeLayout.XConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Width, Factor=2.5}" 
                   RelativeLayout.YConstraint="{ConstraintExpression Type=RelativeToParent, Property=Height, Factor= .7}">
                <Grid BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                    <magicGradients:GradientView VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <magicGradients:GradientView.GradientSource>
                        <magicGradients:LinearGradient Angle="111">
                                <magicGradients:GradientStop Color="#DADDFB" Offset="0" />
                                <magicGradients:GradientStop Color="#DADDFB" Offset=".4" />
                                <magicGradients:GradientStop Color="#DADDFB" Offset=".6" />
                            </magicGradients:LinearGradient>
                    </magicGradients:GradientView.GradientSource>
                </magicGradients:GradientView>
                        <Button Text="Sign up" TextColor="Black" BorderWidth="0" BorderColor ="Transparent" Clicked="SignupCommand" BackgroundColor="Transparent" />
                    </Grid>
            </Frame>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </Grid>

    </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

[image]

[image]

After looking for the cause all day Im starting to believe it has to be some sort of configuration setting acting up? If there is any other code you'd like to see from my project feel free to ask.

Thinking about just putting code in fresh solution to see if that solves it but id rather save that as a last resort since its probably gonna be a pain in the ass.

Edit 1: Im thinking it may also be something with navigation itself and currently that's the direction I'm looking in.

Thanks for any suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for anyone who stumbles across this post looking for an answer to a similar problem, I figured out an easy way to remove the navigation bar.

You can just set `HasNavigationBar` to false like so:

```xml
<ContentPage NavigationPage.HasNavigationBar = "False">
```